# How to change Unix Timestamp to Human Date in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, unix-timestamp

I've seen a couple of posts doing the reverse for mysql, but I'm looking for a way to change a unix timestamp to a human readable date (ideally one I can change the format of) and I haven't been able to find anything so far.

I'm storing a date pulled from an XML feed, via NokoGiri (in Rails 3.1.1) as part of a hash:

```
'date' => i.xpath('@unix-timestamp')
```

which gets the number fine, but how the devil do you make this DD-MM-YYYY to be put in one of my views?

I've tried Time.at( (i.xpath('@unix-timestamp') ) to no avail; I just get the error 'can't convert Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet into an exact number' and now I've hit a wall

Much gratitude for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`Time.at` is definitely a call that should work to convert from epoch time to a ruby Time object (see [here](http://whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Dates_and_times#How_do_I_create_a_Time_object_from_a_Unix_timestamp.3F) for an example).  So it seems like you need to work on converting your XML result into something more usable.  I think you want to try using [NodeSet#text](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#M000282) to get a string output, then converting that to an integer:

```
Time.at(i.xpath('@unix-timestamp').text.to_i)
```

There's a decent but basic tutorial for NokoGiri in the [Engineyard blog](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/)

Comment: Not sure if you also needed help with the second half (turning a Time into a particular human-readable format, but the thing for that is `.strftime`, and there's a nice reference for it here: http://strfti.me/

Answer (score 1):

You can use like : `DateTime.strptime("1373210218",'%s')`

and also `Time.at(1373210218).strftime("%B %e, %Y at %I:%M %p")`